# How to disable an onClick method associated with multiple views?

Tags: java, android, layout, onclick

I don't want to allow the user to be able to click on the various images (which have onClick="mark") and call the method mark().

Method mark:

```
public void mark(View view){
    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
    counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);
    sett(view);
}
```

Instead I want only method retro() to be accessible when it is called.
Method retro:

```
public void retro(View v){
    Button bq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1) ;
    bq.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
    bq.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
    //restart(bq);
}
```

So what should I add to retro() in order to disable mark()

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you want to allow clicking on only some images that have `onclick=retro`?

Comment: Set the onclicklistener to null

Comment: @Napster Yes that's correct, retro() makes a button appear, and I want only that button to be clickable. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I am new to programing, can you tell me more about how to set onclicklistener to null in the retro() method. Thank you for helping! @JRowan

Comment: You can just disable the buttons that you don't want users to click on using `<button_object>.setEnabled(false)`. I am still slightly unsure what you are trying to achieve with the function `mark` then if you don't want to call the method `mark()`

Comment: bq .setOnClickListener(null);

Answer (score 0):

So you know which View is calling the method. It's like implementing the OnClickListener for you activity, the method created is onClick(View v) (or arg0 depending on your Eclipse), defining it from xml is just specifying a sort of listener for the View, and the method from the listener as that argument.

Once you're in the method, you can do a switch for the id of the button, to perform different actions:

```
public void myOnClickMethod(View v)
{
switch(v.getId())
{
   case R.id.button1:
      //Do something for button 1
   break;
   case R.id.button2:
      //Do something for button 2
   break;
}
}
```

In short. Android just implements the OnClickListener for you when you define the android:onClick="myOnClickMethod" attribute.